# snowflake extract all values from nested JSON enclosed with string

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, procedure

I have a JSON in below format returning from procedure in snowflake

```json
[
  {
    "A": "[{\"A\":\"5854\"}]"
  },
  {
    "B": "[{\"B\":\"5681\"}]"
  },
  {
    "FYM": "[{\"200701\":\"202112\",\""\":\"177\"}]"
  }
]
```

I am expecting output in below format

| COL_NAME | VALUE | MIN_DT | MAX_DT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5854 |  |  |
| B | 5681 |  |  |
| FYM | 177 | 200701 | 202112 |

Below is the code I have tried

```
SELECT DISTINCT object_keys(value)[0] AS col_name
  FROM table(flatten(:tmp_array))
```

Above query returns below output

| COL_NAME |
| --- |
| "A" |
| "B" |
| "FYM" |

Now to populate **`value`** column I used below query which returns *null*

```
SELECT DISTINCT object_keys(value)[0] AS COL_NAME, object_keys(value:value) AS VALUE
  FROM table(flatten(:tmp_array))
```

Below is the second version to get VALUE column

```
select distinct regexp_replace(object_keys(value)[0],'"','') COL_NAME,TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(value, ':|\\{|\\}|"|\\[|\\]|\\\\|[a-z/-/A-z/./#/*]', ' ')) from table(flatten(:tmp_array)) )
```

Above query returns below output

```
COL_NAME  |VALUE
----------|----------
    A     |5854
    B     |5681
  FYM     |200701 202112,177
```

Now the issues is FYM has 3 values still I haven't achieved expected. Not sure of the approach to create column MAX_DT,MIN_DT

Any help here please